# AutoSuggest Using PHP/MySQL & Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, autosuggest

I have created a Autosuggestion using PHP/MySQL and Ajax but when I click on the search suggestion with ( ' ) on it it doesn't fill up the search box but everything else does. For example I can't click on a search result that says " Just can't get enough." but i can click on " Just cant get enough ". Can you guys tell me why? 
Thanks

The code:

```
<?php
    include('conn2.php');
    $str = strtolower($_GET['content']);         
    if(strlen($str))
    {
        $sel = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM Music WHERE title LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($str))."%'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
        {
            echo "<table border =\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
            if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('1');</script>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
                {
                    $country = str_ireplace($str,"<b>".$str."</b>",($row['title']));
                    echo "<tr id=\"word".$row['title']."\" onmouseover=\"highlight(1,'".$row['title']."');\" onmouseout=\"highlight(0,'".$row['title']."');\" onClick=\"display('".$row['title']."');\" >\n<td>".$country."</td>\n</tr>\n";
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('0');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: convert everything to it's entities in the database and use `htmlentites` on `$_GET['content']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = htmlentities(strtolower($_GET['content']));
```

Also, you can use new filter_input function to prevent SQL injection if you are using new PHP version.

FYI:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that the single-quote in your search result is conflicting with the single-quote in your below HTML line that uses single-quotes for enclosing parameters to the function calls on mouse-over/out/click.

```
echo "<tr 
id=\"word" . $row['title'] . "\" 
onmouseover=\"highlight(1,'" . $row['title'] . "');\" 
onmouseout=\"highlight(0,'" . $row['title'] . "');\" 
onClick=\"display('" . $row['title'] . "');\" >\n
    <td>" . $country . "</td>\n
</tr>\n";
```

As you'll see, both highlight() and display() functions encase the title parameter in single-quotes and a single quotes in the title might conflict with them, thus breaking your HTML. Try escaping single quotes in $row['title'] and it should work then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Aftad: I think you didn't recognize but it is your code, I haven't changed anything to make it work. I just mentioned it in my response to point you to the right line and the issue that might be preventing single-quote in your search results

Comment: so do you know whats the problem?

Comment: @Aftad: I think I'd mentioned the problem in my response that the single-quote in your search result is conflicting with the single-quote in your HTML. Please try escaping the single quotes in `$row['title']`, using either addslashes() or preg_replace(). I'm not sure but perhaps you might need to remove the slashes in the JS function highlight()